# Spring Boot Cloud Hystrix

Tags: spring, hystrix

I am getting "error creating bean with name hystrixstreamendpoint" defined in classpath resource [org/springframework.cloud/netflix/hystrix/Hystrixcircuitbreakerconfiguaration$HystrixWebconfiguaration.class] : invocation of init method failed:

Spring boot maven is

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-parent -->
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.12.RELEASE</version>       
</dependency>

and Hystrix maven is 
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-starter-hystrix -->
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-hystrix</artifactId>
   <version>1.4.7.RELEASE</version>
```

Please help me out. I have been stuck here from last 2 days.

Comment: Try this: https://spring.io/guides/gs/circuit-breaker/

Comment: same error. followed article.

Comment: Hystrix requires Spring Boot >= 2.0.0.RELEASE and < 2.4.0.M1. Check https://start.spring.io/

Comment: got it. i have checked circuit breaker.

Comment: I have used Resilience4j.